# Java program to find integer root of a quadratic equation

Tags: java, floating-point, int, root, quadratic

So, here is my requirement. If a quadratic equation has two roots(an int & a float), I want to take only integer value for further manipulation. I can't figure it out how  it's made. Can anyone tell me please. (Java would be better).

Comment: what have you tried and what are you having trouble with? There are many ways you could test if a number is a whole number. I like `x == (long) x` or `x == Math.round(x)`

Comment: This is the question I was asked.Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n^3, the cube above will have volume of (n-1)^3 and so on until the top which will have a volume of 1^3.

You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?

The parameter of the function findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb) will be an integer m and you have to return the integer n such as n^3 + (n-1)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m if such a n exists or -1 if there is no such n.

Comment: Always share your code while asking. This seems to be home work to me. Anyways i will give you a hint just check whether the integer part of the number is equal to number..if it is then it is a whole number otherwise a floating number

Comment: Thank you for giving the hint

Comment: I would use a loop to sum 1^3 + 2^3 etc until you have a matching value or one too large. You don't need to solve roots or use float.

Comment: There is no quadratic equation in the problem statement or immediately apparent in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

[I do not use Java regularly. Here is a solution using C. As only elementary concepts are used, a Java practitioner should be able to translate it readily.]

Searching the web for “sum of cubes” reveals [this page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/) which tells us the sum of *k*<sup>3</sup> for *k* from 1 to *n* is *n*<sup>2</sup>•(*n*+1)<sup>2</sup>/4.

That is a quartic equation, for which closed-form solutions are known, but we easily see that, for positive *n*, *n*<sup>2</sup>•(*n*+1)<sup>2</sup>/4 is between *n*<sup>4</sup>/4 and (*n*+1)<sup>4</sup>/4. Then, if *m* is the sum of the first *n* cubes, *n* = floor((4•*m*)<sup>1/4</sup>). So, if we have a `pow` implementation that is faithfully rounded using round-to-nearest (the computed result is one of the two representable values nearest the mathematical result), we can find *n* with `floor(pow(4*m, .25))`. If `pow` is not faithfully rounded, then `round(pow(4*m, .25))` will serve over the domain for which `pow` returns some reasonable result without too much error. (`round` works because (4•*m*)<sup>1/4</sup> never exceeds *n* by more than ½. Proof omitted, although [Wolfram Alpha shows us the limit as *n* goes to ∞ is ½](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B-n+%2B+%28n%5E2+%281+%2B+n%29%5E2%29%5E%281%2F4%29,+n+-%3E+Infinity%5D), and the excess is monotonic.)

Thus, if *m* is the sum of the first *n* cubes, then *n* is the result of `round(pow(4*m, .25))`. So we can compute this value for *n*, then compute the sum of the first *n* cubes as `n*n*(n+1)*(n+1)/4` and test whether that equals *m*. If it does, we found a solution and return it. If it does not, *m* is not a sum of cubes, and we return −1:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static double findNb(double m)
{
    double n = round(pow(4*m, .25));
    double sum = n * n * (n+1) * (n+1) / 4;
    return m == sum ? n : -1;
}

static void Test(double m)
{
    printf("findNb(%.99g) -> %.99g.\n", m, findNb(m));
}

int main(void)
{
    Test(0);
    Test(1);
    Test(2);
    Test(8);
    Test(9);
    Test(10);
    Test(250500249999.);
    Test(250500250000.);
    Test(250500250001.);
}
```

Output:

```
findNb(0) -> 0.
findNb(1) -> 1.
findNb(2) -> -1.
findNb(8) -> -1.
findNb(9) -> 2.
findNb(10) -> -1.
findNb(250500249999) -> -1.
findNb(250500250000) -> 1000.
findNb(250500250001) -> -1.
```

Of course, the limits of floating-point precision will cause this code to fail once *m* is larger than can be represented in `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the basic quadatic formula to find the roots.

Set the roots to different values (both doubles)

Use modulous (%) by 1 and cast the value to a double. If the double calculated is !=0, then it is not an int.